# URI Escape for strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, escaping, url-encoding

I am referencing an API for developing an application for a social platform called Mixi. I am stuck at a point where it says the following:
For a parameter to be passed correctly to payment API, the string must be URI escaped according to [the following rules](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#encoding_parameters):

> All parameter names and values are escaped using the [RFC3986]
>   percent-encoding (%xx) mechanism. Characters not in the unreserved
>   character set ([RFC3986] section 2.3) MUST be encoded. Characters in
>   the unreserved character set MUST NOT be encoded. Hexadecimal
>   characters in encodings MUST be upper case. Text names and values MUST
>   be encoded as UTF-8 octets before percent-encoding them per [RFC3629].
>
> ```
> unreserved = ALPHA, DIGIT, '-', '.', '_', '~'
> ```

I am really confused looking at this page. I intend to do this in Javascript/jQuery. Is there a simple way or function to achieve this ? Please suggest if there is some external library that can do this if jQuery directly can not.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The site policy discourages (for good reasons) questions and answers that are nothing but a link to an external site... and you even encoded the link as code so it wasn't clickable. I've edited the question and fixed these issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for UTF-8 encodeing, you can use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

`var encodedURI = encodeURIComponent(str);`